Convert String to Array with numeric values only
I have the below dataweave code (maybe not the best one) to check if an array contains any non-numeric elements. It also check for the number of items in the array.
%dw 2.0
output json
fun isValidElements(arr: Array) =
    arr map ((item) -> item is Number and item != null) reduce ((acc, item) -> acc and item)
fun isValidArray(arr: Array) =
    (sizeOf(arr) > 0) and (isEmpty(arr) or isValidElements(arr))
fun flagInvalidArray(arr: Array) = isValidArray(arr)
var MyArray = [123,456,789]
---
{
    "arrayValid": flagInvalidArray(MyArray),
    "arraySize": if (sizeOf(MyArray) > 1) "Multiple" else "Single"
}

As you can see this checks for string and nulls and flags if any array is valid or not (It is considered valid if it contains only numeric items)
Now, I need to do this check for a string array. i.e. if my input is like this "[123,456,789]".
If I do a conversion like this read(MyArray,"application/json"), it works fine. However it fails when I have any other non-numeric value in the string array. Few examples of how my string array will look like:
"[ABC,123,456,789]"
"[123,null,456]"
"[,,,,,%$$$]" -- In cases where there are junk values, we can make the array as empty and flag it as invalid

Edit:
My requirement is to make sure that the array (in string format) that I have doesn't contain any non-numeric items. For example: "[123,456,789]" and "[12345]" are valid arrays. If I get any non-numeric characters inside the array or if it's an empty array, I need to flag it as invalid. That's where I'm looking for a function. Examples of invalid array: "[123,ABC,456]", "["ABC",456]", [], [123,456,null]

It is not clear which is the expected input and expected outputs.Show actual examples. Also what is a valid string array? Please explain that. Are you reading an string input that contains an array? Those examples are not JSON arrays encoded inside a string.

flagInvalidArray() does nothing. arraySize is not related to the question. Try to minimize your example.

Apologies for not being clear. My requirement is to make sure that the array (in string format) that I have doesn't contain any non-numeric items.
For example: "[123,456,789]" and "[12345]" are valid arrays.
If I get any non-numeric characters inside the array or if it's an empty array, I need to flag it as invalid. That's where I'm looking for a function.
Examples of invalid array: "[123,ABC,456]", "["ABC",456]", [], [123,456,null]
Hope this helps.

You should edit the question with that clarification. As it is it now is not clear. I updated my answer.

If you are trying to validate that all the elements of an array comply with a condition it is easy to implement that with the every() function of the Arrays module.
I implemented this function with the condition that the array must no be empty and every element is a number. You can modify the condition as needed. I used the try()/orElse() first to read the input string as JSON. This will work only because a JSON numeric array matches your inputs, but it doesn't seem your inputs are really JSON.
I added some example inputs to show the results.
%dw 2.0
output json
import * from dw::core::Arrays
import * from dw::Runtime

fun isValidNumericArray(arr: Array) =
    !isEmpty(arr) and (arr every ((item) -> item is Number))

fun isStringNumericArray(s: String) = 
    try(() -> isValidNumericArray(read(s,"application/json"))) orElse false
 
---
{
    "valid": isStringNumericArray( "[123,456,789]" ),
    "emptyArray": isStringNumericArray( "[]" ),
    "nullItem": isStringNumericArray( "[123,null,456]" ),
    "string": isStringNumericArray( "[ABC,123,456,789]" ),
    "junk": isStringNumericArray("[,,,,,%\$]")
}

Output:
{
  "valid": true,
  "emptyArray": false,
  "nullItem": false,
  "string": false,
  "junk": false
}

